# Flutter: value of type 'Future<List<UserVideo>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<UserVideo>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use one List (custom type) but getting error.

When i try to use the getData() function. Like below.

```
List<UserVideo> videoDataList = [];

videoDataList = UserVideo.getData();
```

This is initState method.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    videoDataList = await UserVideo.getData();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _videoListController.init(
      _pageController,
      videoDataList,
   
    );

    super.initState();
  }
```

I am getting the error.

```
A value of type 'Future<List<UserVideo>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<UserVideo>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<UserVideo>'.
```

Here is the code for function.

```
class UserVideo {
  final String url;
  final String image;
  final String desc;

  UserVideo({
    this.url: mockVideo,
    this.image: mockImage,
    this.desc,
  });

 Future <List<UserVideo>> getData() async {
    List<UserVideo> list = [];
    try {
      var deviceid = '123';
      var dtgUid = '100';

      var nodata;

      var bodyss = {
        "uid": dtgUid,
        "deviceid": deviceid,

      };

      var url = 'http://192.168.100.4:8080/videos/get-data.php';

      // Starting Web API Call.
      var response = await http
          .post(url, body: json.encode(bodyss))
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5), onTimeout: () {
        return null;
      });
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = StreamingFromJson(response.body);
        if (data.count == null) {
          count = 0;
        } else {
          count = data.count;
        }
        if (data.content.length > 0 && data.content[0].name != 'Empty') {
          for (var i in data.content) {
            list.add(UserVideo(image: i.thumbnail, url: i.video, desc: i.title));
          }
        } else {
          nodata = 'No Record Found';
        }
        print(list.length);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Exception Caught: $e");
    }
    return list;
  }
```

Edit:

Just showing the hardcoded value which is working fine.

```
static List<UserVideo> fetchVideo() {
    List<UserVideo> list = [];
    list.add(UserVideo(image: '', url: mockVideo, desc: 'Test1'));
    list.add(UserVideo(image: '', url: mV2, desc: 'MV_TEST_2'));
    list.add(UserVideo(image: '', url: mV3, desc: 'MV_TEST_3'));
    list.add(UserVideo(image: '', url: mV4, desc: 'MV_TEST_4'));
    return list;
  }
```

I can use it like this and no error.

```
videoDataList = UserVideo.fetchVideo();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `getData()` returns a Future:

```
 Future<List<UserVideo>> getData() async {
    List<UserVideo> list = [];
    try {
      var deviceid = '123';
      var dtgUid = '100';

      var nodata;

      var bodyss = {
        "uid": dtgUid,
        "deviceid": deviceid,

      };
```

You have to use `async/await` to call the method `getData()`:

```
List<UserVideo> videoDataList = [];
videoDataList = await UserVideo.getData();
```

or use `then()`:

```
List<UserVideo> videoDataList = [];
UserVideo.getData().then((list){
   videoDataList = list;
 });
```

Note: To use `await` you need to declare a method `async`

Comment: Thanks for the answer peter. let me try. I was trying to use it in Init method. Updatin the question with more code. Await is giving error. The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.dart(await_in_wrong_context)

Comment: I checked the edit and tried then method. now it is giving error Instance member 'getData' can't be accessed using static access.

Comment: you need to create an instance of UserVideo class and then call getData

Comment: I think Class is already created. Check my question.If i hardcode the value then not getting error. Adding code of hard coded value. Its updated at end of the question.

Comment: You need to create an instance of the class (object), you cannot call getData() like that.. You have to do `var userVideo = UserVideo()` then do `userVideo.getData()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217201/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-rocx).